# Existence of function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ which has partial derivates as given functions.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $F_{1},F_{2}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be the  functions $$F_{1}(x_{1},x_{2})=\frac{-x_{2}}{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}, F_{2}=\frac{-x_{1}}{x_{1}^{2}+x_{2}^{2}}.$$ How to prove that there is no function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2}/(0,0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=F_{1},and~\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=F_{2}$$ But there exist such function on any open disc that does not contain zero. I have no idea that  which concept should i use for the problem. I know only that $$ \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}=\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}$$ Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure about the problem statement? There seems to be some confusion between $x_1,x_2$ and $x,y.$

Comment: yes i think i does't matter if you say $x_{1}$ for $x.$

Comment: Do you know the definition of path integrals for vector fields?

Comment: no but what is the relation of this question with path integral...

Comment: ok i m editing it..

Comment: A (continuous) vector field is a gradient field if and only if the path integral over every closed curve vanishes. That gives you a criterion to check if you know path integrals.

Comment: @neela even after your edit the identity $ \frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial x_{2}}=\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x_{1}}$ is still false.

Comment: @neela you shouldn't be so sure, especially when you're wrong... You made a sign mistake

Comment: ok sorry for that ....

Comment: I have deleted some of my previous comments because I think now that the original problem statements had the correct partial derivatives! (sorry about that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the identity $\frac{\partial F_{1}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial F_{2}}{\partial x}$ is satisfied then a function $f$ can be constructed locally around a point $(x_0,y_0)$ by

$$\eqalign{
f(x,y)&=\int_{s=x_0}^xF_1(s,y_0)\int_{t=y_0}^yF_2(x,t)dt\ ds\\
&\hbox{ or, alternatively,}\\
\overline f(x,y)&=\int_{t=y_0}^yF_2(t,y_0)\int_{s=x_0}^xF_1(s,y)dt\ ds\\
}$$

This works as long as the path of integration (two line segments in both cases) does not hit the origin, and the two integrals are identical as long as the rectangle described by the four line segments does not include the origin.

The result of this integration can be described in global form only if we cut out some line that connects the origin to infinity. The easiest description is the "argument" function: the oriented angle of $(x,y)$ measured counterclockwise from the positive $X$-axis. It is locally equal to $f(x,y)=\arctan(y/x)$ up to a constant but there is an ambiguity on the negative $X$-axis. You can verify directly that the partial derivatives of this function are your $F_1$ and $F_2.$

The nonexistence of any global solution can be proven by noting that such a global solution must differ from the argument function by a constant on the domain of definition of the argument function, and then we get two different limits ($-\pi$ and $+\pi$) approaching the negative $X$-axis from two sides.

Comment: please can you give me book name which are suitable for this concept...thanks..

Comment: I would recommend any book on elementary differential geometry that pays sufficient attention to either or both of the subjects "differential forms" and "integrability conditions." My favourite is chapters 6 and 7 of the first volume of M.Spivak, "A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry." Proposition 0 of chapter 6 is very close to what we are doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Hint : You should check Schwarz Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives

Edit : if there is such a $f$, then $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2}=\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2 \partial x_1}$ which is not the case because $\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x_2}=-\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x_1}$

Comment: if possible give some calculation in your answer..